# Search results shows everything in database and show image in results

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a search function in my laravel project, when I navigate to the search page it shows all the entries in the database. I would like it to show nothing until I put something in the search field. Furthermore, when the results are displayed I would like an image to be dispalyed.
Here are the relavent files:

```
public function search(Request  $request){
    $query = $request->input('query');
    $result = Photo::search($query)->get();
    return view('search.results')->with('result', $result);

   }
```

Here is the model

```
class Photo extends Model

{
use SearchableTrait;

   protected $searchable = [
   
   'columns' => [
       'photos.title' => 10,
       'photos.description' => 10,
       'photos.photo' => 10,
      ],

   ];

   protected $fillable = array('photo','title','description','album_id');

public function album(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\Album');
}
```

}

The display.blade.php

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-8">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-stripped">
    <thead>
       <tr>
         <th>Image</th>
         <th>Title</th>
         <th>Description</th>
       </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($result as $res)
       <tr>
         <th><img src="/storage/photos/."{{$album_id}}/{{$res->photo}}</a></th>
         <th>{{$res->title}}</th>
         <th>{{$res->description}}</th>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

In the above code I get an error message about not being able to find $album_id.

As always thank you for your help

Comment: What's happens if you `dd ($result)` right after you define `$result` ? you should get an array as output that should include your `$album_id` as property. Otherwise your `photo::search` query is not well built. Is your `$album_id` in `photos` table?

Comment: nevermind last comment, just change `{{ $album_id }}` to `{{ $res->album_id }}`

Comment: I have fixed the second part of my question.

Comment: Cloud yo pelease mark response as useful if it did solve your problem

Comment: I have decided to do the search routine a different way. I plan to use components and particals. I am sure I will have some questions about that. Thank you